# Error when running gradle command despite upgrading wrapper

Tags: android, gradle

I already set this to my gradle.properties
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

when I type command `gradle` it always show error

`Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1.  Current version is 2.11. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl`

did I miss something?

here is my build.gradle (project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

gradle.build ( module)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio go to your preferences and check search for Gradle, you can verify there what version of gradle is actually in use

Comment: Android studio must have not retrieved the gradle wrapper mapping to the version in your distributionUrl.  Let the gradle project sync.

Comment: I am using intellij

Comment: can you tell me what is your `buildToolsVersion` ?

Comment: @Ironman  buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

Comment: @jemz add both gradle in the question. `build.gradle`(Project) and `build.gradle` (Module). because in the question you are putting less information so i can't figure out what is the actual problem.

Comment: @Ironman, I updated now

Comment: @jemz do one thing go to `File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Gradle` and Select `Use default gradle wrapper`. and run again. see what is happen when you use default gradle wrapper.

Comment: @Ironman, still having problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when I type command `gradle`" indicates that you are starting the build from the command line. In this case use `gradlew` from the projects root directory otherwise the wrapper will not be used. The command `gradle` starts the gradle version permanently installed on the box.

Try `gradle --version` and `./gradlew --version` to confirm.

Comment: gradle version is 2.11 and gradlew is 2.14.1 ...can you please enlighten me on gradle and gradlew I am little bit confuse..

Comment: You can install gradle permanently and then use the `gradle` command to run it. Or you can use the gradle wrapper command `gradlew` which first downloads the gradle version mentioned in the distribution url (unless it is already downloaded) and then runs it.

Comment: Thank you @Henry...by the way if you don't mind do you have books to recommend in android ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by doing this although answer is accepted but still if someone still need help try this

Go to File -> setting search for gradle

you will see build,execution,deployment->gradle for current project at the top

in project level settings change use local gradle distribution to use default gradle wrapper(Recommended)